# ARKit – Not able to detect a plane

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am not able to detect surface using ARKit. I have also added the image of the surface.

How to detect a surface with less texture accurately?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> To successfully detect a `horizontal` or `vertical` plane using ARKit or RealityKit you need to track:

- surfaces with distinguished textures;
- in a well-lit environment;
- you must ***physically*** move around a room;

> You do not need to track:

- surfaces with "poor" or repetitive textures;
- glare, reflective or refractive surfaces;
- transparent objects (like glass tables);

However, to overcome most of these limitations, you can use the iPad Pro with a LiDAR scanner. iPad Pro 2020 detects surfaces at unprecedented speed (at tens of nanoseconds) in a poorly-lit room.